# Как реализовать midjorney в виде бота?

Tags: python, бот

Хотим реализовать midjorney в виде бота. Но у нее нет API.

Нашли клиентскую версию, которую можно загрузить на хост и так сделать. Но она старая.

Есть также предположение работать через API Discord.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону стоит копать.

Comment: Прям midjourney реализовать как собственного бота - это бот для работы с ботом. А чем stable diffusion хуже? Реализовать через тот же самый API гуишки AUTOMATIC1111 GUI для SD.

Comment: Вроде как существуют модели SD околоподобные или даже лучше midjourney во всех планах

Answer (score -1):

Есть готовые апи под это дело по типу [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai) (это API прослойка для Midjourney), в тысячу раз проще, чем писать свое решение